# UINavigationBar shouldn't scroll with table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a Navigation Bar, But it scrolling with my tableview. How Can I fixed it?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navigationBar;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding a `UINavigationBar` (I hope you do mean `UINavigationBar` and not `UINavigationItem`) as a subview of the table view, create a `UINavigationController` and make your table view controller the root controller of the navigation controller.

This way you get a navigation bar and optionally a toolbar for free and everything works as you would expect it.

Please read the "View Controller Programming Guide" for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the table header, not the table itself. If you play around with IB and move your nav bar up to the top of the table, it will give you an option to put it in the table header. Or if you are adding it programmatically, use the tableheader attribute.